# Problema con JS querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, html

tengo un problema con js, recien lo aprendo y estoy haciendo una pagina tipo encuesta , pero no puedo hacer que salgan los nombres seleccionados

```
<td>
                Deportes favoritos
            </td>
            <td >
                <input type="checkbox" id="ch1" name="deporte" value="ciclismo">ciclismo
                <br>
                <input type="checkbox" id="ch2" name="deporte" value="tenis">tenis
                <br>
                <input type="checkbox" id="ch3" name="deporte" value="natacion">natacion
                <br>
                <input type="checkbox" id="ch4" name="deporte" value="karate">karate
            </td>
```

y asi tengo la funcion :

```
function datos(){
        var nb;
        var sx;
        var dp;

        nb=document.getElementById('txtnombre').value;
        sx=document.querySelector('input[name=sex]:checked').value 
        dp=document.querySelectorAll('input[name=deporte]:checked')
        for(var i=0;i<dp.length;i++){
            console.log(dp)

        }

    document.write('<table border="2" cellspacing="0" align="center">')
    document.write('<th align=center colspan=2>Datos registrados</th>')
    document.write('<tr><td align=center>Nombre :</td><td>'+nb+'</td></tr>')
    document.write('<tr><td align=center>Sexo :</td><td>'+sx+'</td></tr>')
    document.write('<tr><td align=center>Deportes favoritos :</td><td>'+dp+'</td></tr>')
    document.write('</table')
    }
```

Me sale este error 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver si me cuenta lo que elijo en el checkbox , pero no lo puedo mostrar por nombre , solo puse el for para ver si me estaba guardando los checks

Gracias por su respuestas...

Comment: No se entiende bien lo que pretendes conseguir. Lo primero de todo: ¿Cuándo quieres lanzar la función `datos()`? ¿Qué elemento es el que tiene la `id="txtnombre"`? En tu **HTML** no lo tienes, al igual que tampoco tienes ningún `<input>` con nombre **sex**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si he entendido bien, lo que quieres es listar en la tabla los deportes que el usuario haya seleccionado. Tal y como lo tienes, lo que estas tratando de mostrar es un `array` ya que el método `querySelectorAll()` nos devuelve una colección con todos los elementos que coincidan con el selector (de ahí que te imprima en la tabla *object NodeList*).

Para poder listar los valores de los deportes seleccionados tendrías que iterar esa colección e ir accediendo a cada una de sus posiciones para sacar el valor de cada elemento.

```html
<td>
    Deportes favoritos
</td>
<td >
    <input type="checkbox" id="ch1" name="deporte" value="ciclismo">ciclismo
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="ch2" name="deporte" value="tenis">tenis
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="ch3" name="deporte" value="natacion">natacion
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="ch4" name="deporte" value="karate">karate
</td>

<button type="button" onclick="datos()">Comprobar</button>

<script>
  function datos() {
    var nb;
    var sx;
    var dp;

    nb="Fulanito";
    sx="Poco";
    dp=document.querySelectorAll('input[name=deporte]:checked');

    document.write('<table border="2" cellspacing="0" align="center">');
    document.write('<th align=center colspan=2>Datos registrados</th>');
    document.write('<tr><td align=center>Nombre :</td><td>'+nb+'</td></tr>');
    document.write('<tr><td align=center>Sexo :</td><td>'+sx+'</td></tr>');
    document.write('<tr><td align=center>Deportes favoritos :</td><td>');

    for(var i=0;i<dp.length;i++){
       document.write(dp[i].value + '<br>'); 
    }
  
    document.write('</td></tr>');
    document.write('</table');
  }
</script>
```